# Material-UI Divider doesn't show and prevents other elements from showing?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use the MUI divider in React. However, [it doesn't seem to work](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-fog-ntzru); I currently have:

```
import * as React from "react";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import ShareIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Share";
import ReportGmailerrorredIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ReportGmailerrorred";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";

import "./settings.css";

function Settings() {
  return (
    <div className="body">
      <div className="media_interact">
        <div className="media_buttons">
          <IconButton size="medium" sx={{ ml: 2 }}>
            <ShareIcon fontSize="large" />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton size="medium" sx={{ ml: 2 }}>
            <ReportGmailerrorredIcon fontSize="large" />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider
          orientation="vertical"
          variant="middle"
          flexItem
          sx={{ color: "black" }}
        />
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Settings;
```

which, as you can see from the Sandbox, doesn't produce the Divider at all and the `Hello` text element after:

[image]

I'm hoping for some guidance in terms of how to use it?

Comment: In the link you provided, the code appears to work correctly, the divider and the hello text are visible.

Comment: Ah, it seems it appears off the screen. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Perhaps the output window size was smaller, and the divider got hidden within the window border, and because the after pseudo element is relative to the divider, it was also not shown.